# How can I manually mark a photo/video as successfully published in Lightroom 4?

Tags: lightroom-4, publishing

I'm using Lightroom 4 on Windows 7 to manage my photos and videos.  I also use it to publish photos and videos to SmugMug. I recently published a video that is about 700 MB in size.  Lightroom indicated that the publish failed due to a timeout.  However, the publish was in fact successful, because the video now shows up in the gallery on SmugMug and can be viewed from start to finish.  But in Lightroom, the video is still listed in the "New Photos to Publish" section of the published collection.

How can I force Lightroom to consider the video as successfully published so that it doesn't try to include it in the next publish of the collection it is in?

Comment: what will happen if you delete the video from the published collection in Lightroom and do a sync with SmugMug? I believe it should pull the video from SmugMug and put in the collection again

Comment: That strategy has been suggested by SmugMug's support team as well, though it hasn't worked reliably (they're investigating why). It almost certainly doesn't work if the video is re-encoded as part of the publish, or so they tell me. They had me upload the video via the HTML5 uploader, make sure it wasn't in the publish collection, and then sync. I did so with 2 videos in the same gallery. When I did the sync, one of the two was added to the publish collection while the other wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

The "mark as up-to-date" option is only available for items that have already been published and flagged to be re-published.

Answer (score 1):

Lightroom doesn't appear to offer any inbuilt support for marking a photo/video in the 'New Photos to Publish' section as published without first publishing it.

However the [Lightroom 4 SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshoplightroom.html) exposes a LrPublishedCollection:addPhotoByRemoteId method that allows you to mark the photo as published when adding it. If you can obtain the remoteID and remoteURL parameters that the method requires from the video on SmugMug you should be able to write a plugin to add the video without having to publish it again.

If the photo/video has previously been successfully published you can right-click on the video in the publish collection and select the 'Mark as Up-To-Date' option in the context menu.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see that option in the right-click context menu.

Comment: On Windows it's the second-to-last option in the context menu

Comment: Please see the following screen capture: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5415472/contextmenu.png

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 (64-bit), Lightroom 4.1 (64-bit), and version 1.0.4.12 of the SmugMug plug-in. Maybe this is a SmugMug plug-in-specific issue?

Comment: I just sent a message to SmugMug's support team, so we'll see if they can provide any insight.

Comment: According to SmugMug's support team:

_The "mark as up-to-date" on the context menu is dependent on the state of the underlying photos/videos. Since yours have never been recorded as published it's not possible to mark them as current (it's only available for images/videos that are already published and then flagged as modified and needing re-published)._